# PHP Regex (different result between + and * )

Tags: php, regex

If I put * in my regex, it doesn't work, if I put +, it works.

`*` should mean 0 or more, `+` should mean 1 or more.

---

Case with *

```
$num = '    527545855   ';
var_dump( preg_match( '/\d*/', substr( $num, 0, 18 ), $coincidencias ) );
var_dump($coincidencias);exit;
```

Result:

```
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

---

Case with +

```
$num = '    527545855   ';
var_dump( preg_match( '/\d+/', substr( $num, 0, 18 ), $coincidencias ) );
var_dump($coincidencias);exit;
```

Result:

```
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "527545855"
}
```

I thought both should work, but I don't understand why the * doesn't work.

Comment: Why `substr`? You can just pass in `$num`.

Comment: Try and see what happens when you use `preg_match_all()` instead...

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for the tip! I see all the occurences now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would match the digits or **nothing**

`\d*` means match  **0** to many digits

---

For Example in

`hello 123`

the regex `\d*`

would match **8 times** i.e 1 at start(`^`) ,6 times for `hello` and 1 time for `123`

Answer (score 7):

`*` means 0 or more occurences thus the first occurence is the void string in your test string

Answer (score 4):

The engine will attempting to match starting from index 0.

- Since `\d*` can match an empty string, the engine will return the empty string at index 0.
- In contrast, `\d+` must match at least one digit, and since the quantifier is greedy, it will return the nearest sequence of digits, while taking as many digits as possible (in your case, it is the whole sequence of digits in the input string).

Answer (score 4):

You answered this in your question:

`* should mean 0 or more, + should mean 1 or more.`

The first thing that it matched was **0** or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` in a regex takes the character before it and looks for 0 or more instances.
The `+` in a regex looks for 1 or more instances.

Since you aren't really checking around the number (caring for other items) you will get more items back from the regex with `*` since it allows for the 0 instance clause to be met, which is valid for all your spaces before the number (a space is matching 0 instances of a number).  The `+` ensures **at least** one is found.